# Disabling gpgcheck with tmprepo plugin

Tags: linux, yum

I want to install an rpm from a repo just once and not have to add it to my yum.repos.d/ directory using the tmprepo plugin. However, I’m blocked on how to install an rpm with no gpg signature. The ‘—nogpgcheck’ option doesn’t work with the tmprepo plugin and I need to manually append ‘pkgs_gpgcheck=false’ to /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/tmprepo.conf.

```
sudo yum --tmprepo=http://edge.artifactory.example.com:8000/artifactory/chef_rpms/rhel/chef_rpms.repo --nogpgcheck  install chef

## ^^ this fails as —nogpgcheck doesn’t work with tmprepo which defaults to gpgcheck unless I manually edit /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/tmprepo.conf
```

Any way this can be done when calling yum on command line? I don’t want to go about changing a file on the system for a one-time thing. Thanks!

- Faheem

Answer (score 0):

So when using tmprepo for a one-time yum install, can't disable gpg-check unless editing the file. I think that should be a feature on command line too though. For now, I'm doing a:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo $http://myurl/myrepo.repo;
yum-config-manager --enable myrepo
yum install package
yum-config-manager --disable myrepo
```

I keep the repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo but disable the actual repositories.

Comment: yum-config-manager needs some basic features though. Doesn't have a quiet option. Also, if I '--add-repo' when I already have the repo file existing, it appends. Rather should warn out the repo already exists or allow to over-write it. No point of appending.